# Where is the layout preview in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

I installed Android Studio, but when I edit my layout files, I can't find a live preview! I just see an XML file. How can I see my layout in graphical view?

This is how it looks like in my case:

[image]

Comment: The file you edit is not in the Resources directory...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16644419/unable-to-find-ui-designer-in-the-new-android-studio

Comment: Go to `View -> Tool Windows -> Preview`

Comment: For me, the whole toolbar was missing, I had to enable `View -> Toolbar Buttons`.

Answer (score 359, accepted):

**UPDATE 2 (2020-03-16)**

The newer Android Studio version changed the location of this button. Now if you want to see the layout design preview you will need to press one of the buttons at the top right of your xml. The button that looks like an image icon will open the design dashboard, while the button next to it will open the split view where the design is placed next to the XML code:

[image]

**ORIGINAL (2013-05-21)**

You should have a `Design` button next to the `Text` button under the xml text editor:

[image]

Or you can use the `Preview` button in the upper right corner to add a preview window next to the XML code:

[image]

**UPDATE:**

If you dont have it, then do this: `View` -> `Tool Windows` -> `Preview`

[image]

Comment: i dont have this options at all!!

Comment: You can see in the answer a full screen shot of my IDE and you see that those options exist. You probably have done something with yours to remove those options. Try to redownload Android Studio.

Comment: i updated my question, i put my screenshot. i download it recently and dont change anything!

Comment: As solange points out below, you might not be able to see these two bottom tabs, "Design" and "Text", if you're using the darker Dracula theme. Switch back to the Default theme and see if they are there.

Comment: I have this option but disabled !

Comment: Thank you! My preview disappeared and I could not figure where on earth it went to (I think one of my children must have hit something).  THANK YOU!

Comment: For everyone that cant see the preview on view> windows tool you MUST be in "text" tab on the xml editor to see the option

Comment: This has happened numerous times and I've come back to this answer every time and see that I've already upvoted it.

Comment: when i use coordinatelayout the layout preview is not available in android  studio.for other basic view preview is available please help me.

Comment: I had this problem. View->Tool Windows->Preview was greyed out, even though I have the layout file open. Switching to design tab and then back to text suddenly enables the previously disabled preview window. WTF?

Comment: @RobertTuck, Didn't see this problem, sounds like a bug in Android Studio.

Comment: The `Preview` option on `View` > `Tool Windows` has been removed between version 3.5 and 3.6 of Android Studio. Instead, use the `Design` tab on your resource to see the preview.

Comment: @GustafLiljegren still have it in the latest stable version (3.5.1)

Comment: Could this question be streamlined to not include so many upgrades? For people who find this answer now it's not really especially interesting to dig through all the updates to find what they need. Ideally we'd have the current version at the top with older versions still mentioned below for those who use older versions of Android Studio.

Answer (score 56):

Several people seem to have the same problem. The issue is that the IDE only displays the preview if editing a layout file in the `res/layout*` directory of an Android project.

In particular, it won't show if editing a file in `build/res/layout*` since those are not **source** directory but **output** directory. In your case, you are editing a file in the `build/` directory...

The Resource folder is set automatically, and can be viewed (and changed) in Project Structure > Modules > [Module name] > Android > Resources directory.

Comment: there is no Android tab and no Resources feature as you describe, at least in current actual Android studio 1.1.0
[link](http://screenshot.net/2rmjju8.jpg)

Comment: Yeah, it seems Android Studio handles it automatically now; I believe one can not accidentally open an output file anymore.

Comment: Oh my god, was getting crazy with this !! Thank you !

Answer (score 19):

1. Select MainActivity.java file from the left pane, as shown in the red colored rectangle.
2. Left click the XML Tag icon as shown in the red colored circle.
3. Select the "activity_main.xml(layout)" option shown highlighted in the below figure.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! This fixed.

Comment: This is the right answer. Took me 20 minutes to fix.

Answer (score 17):

In case that helps anyone, I had the same issue today where the 'design / text' tabs were missing. I had switched to the dark theme and thought maybe that was the issue, so went back to Preferences / Appearance (under IDE settings) switched back to Default Theme, and that reset everything correctly for me. I could also then switch again to Darcula theme and the tabs were still there, so seems like switching themes is a way to reset the IDE windows/tabs.

Comment: Boom! Thank you. I had the same issue where I was using the Dracula theme and had to switch back to the Default theme in order to see the "Design" and "Text" tabs visible at the bottom. Cheers.

Comment: I was missing the tabs on the bottom, this worked for me with the latest release as of 9/25/13. However, it didnt switch my theme back, just the code editor window.. still fairly buggy.. great promise though

Answer (score 12):

The following worked for me:

-> file

-> settings

-> plugins

-> disable the android support plugin

-> you will be prompted to restart

-> once restarted re-enable the plugin and other dependency plugins that might have been disabled in the process

-> you will be prompted to restart once again. Hopefully when android studio restarts the second time the preview should render.

Answer (score 10):

I found 2 quick options to fix this:

1. Just input in search "Preview" and it will show you a single result. Just click on it and preview appears again :)
2. Pull the right-side line and window will appear. It's kinda resize.

[image: Preview window in android studio]

Happy coding!

Answer (score 8):

For those struggling in **Android Studio 3.6**:

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Go to File->Invalidate Caches / Restart.

This will solve the issue.

Answer (score 5):

Got the same problem after importing my Eclipse ADT project to Android Studio. Text and Desing tabs where missing.

Found my Event Log windows reads 
"Frameworks detected: Android framework is detected in the project Configure"

I click the hyperlink provided and everything was fixed, Text and Desing tabs became visible and functional

Answer (score 4):

Navigate to file -> Project structure -> modules -> click on green plus button to add a module.

Select new module -> select Application Module in Android option -> give a module name -> next -> next -> finish

Select project that to be include in module -> click apply -> okay

Now you will be able to see the full project structure; then open the module form project window (the left panel), select res then select layout -> your layout name(.xml).

Now you will be able to see the design view and text view both...

Answer (score 2):

As etienne said be sure that the XML file you are looking at is in `src/main/res/layout`

I had the same issue. If you're in a layout file in `build` directory, you won't see a preview, nor will you have it as an option to enable. I wish Google had a slight warning for it.

Answer (score 2):

first of all after creating the new app

go to java->MainActivity

and open a new tab for it

In the java code click on the index numberings where you can see the code logo[image]

as red circled in picture

left click on it and you will see two options as shown in below picture[image]

click on the first option so that you can preview your app in android studio

Answer (score 1):

If you want to see the **live preview**, in the right part of the screen you should have a button call **Preview** that show/hide the live preview.

If what you want is to use the WYSISYG editor mode, in the bottom of the editor there is a tab that switch between **XML** mode and **WYSISYG** mode.

This works in the same way both in IntelliJ and Android Studio.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and resolved by editing the t file in src>main>res>layout. You can choose between Test and Design mode at the bottom of editor.

Quite simple if we know where to look for !!! spend few hours figuring it out!!!

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem a couple hours ago when I exported my projects from Eclipse to Android Studio. Unfortunately, the top answers here didn't work for me.

Anyway, creating a new project instead of opening an old one did the trick for me as what Thomas Kaliakos mentioned on his comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17365015/2792573)

> > *I had to mess around with the project..and at some point it worked. I don't know how though. My guess would be that creating a new project and adding your source code would work every time. Sorry for not being very clear, but honestly I was surprized even myself that it worked.* –  Thomas Kaliakos Oct 15 '13 at 4:08

Answer (score 0):

In case you want docked mode, (it still visible while editing the xml file), and you, by mistake, clicked and unmarked docked mode. In order to get it back you have focus on preview and click `Window > Active Tool Window > Docked Mode`.

Answer (score 0):

If you see a message at the bottom saying something like, "Android Framework detected. Click to configure", DO IT.

After doing this, my Text and Design bottom-tabs appeared.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I don't have *Design* or *Preview* tab.

Try

- Configure the proxy rightly to download necessary components
- Configure the android-sdk path to contains no space character
- Restart Android Studio in Admin mode

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to File->**Invalidate Caches/ Restart**. After restarting the
   preview window will come.
2. Still the preview window is not opened, Go to View -> Tool window -> click **Preview**

Answer (score 0):

Go to File > Settings > Appearance & Behavior > Appearance > Show tool window bars

Answer (score 0):

I am using Android studio 3.3 and this method worked for me:
open settings from file/settings
from the left panel select Editor then layout Editor
then from the right panel uncheck third option which is "Hide preview window when editing non-layout files" then hit apply then ok.
then go to view/tool windows/preview is enable now in the design tab of layout XD. Do not forget up vote and marking this answer as the right answer. Happy coding. [image]

Answer (score 0):

Just need search the appropiate folder that contains your app layour, in this case you can find in your repository folders: **AppName**>res>layout and double click in the layout of your preference activity main normally contains the principal things of your view
[image]

**IMPORTANT**: Check that you have activated the design visualization at the top-right corner (Image icon)

Answer (score 0):

I have Android studio version **"Arctic Fox | 2020.3.1"**.

**Step 1-** Open you xml file.

[image]

**Step 2-** From top right below Gradle you will get Layout Validation option click on it.

[image]

**Step 3 -** Click on "view option" (eye icon) in Layout Validation panel. You will see on drop down with "Show System UI" option. Select this after that you can see preview of your design.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> **The solution is releted to the latest Android Studio Dolphin Version**

After alot of searching and testing, I upgraded my gradle version and its work for me.

Just goto `File -> Project Structure` or press `Ctrl + Alt + Shift + S` and then `upgrate the gradle version` as shown in the image below and then `invalidate cache and restart` the Android Studio and its working

[image]

As shown in the image I upgrade my gradle

Happy Coding With Android Studio :)

Answer (score -1):

File>>setting>>Compiler>>JavaCompiler At "Project bytecode version(leave blank for jdk default):" choose your jdk.

[image]