# How do I show the rich layout editor in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

How do I show or use the rich layout editor talked about in Android Studio?

**More Info**
I'm new to Java and I just downloaded Android Studio and created the Login example. I can't seem to find the "rich layout editor" that is in the brochure. I want to create an app and layout the UI components. I'm trying to learn code by looking at the code that is generated by the rich layout editor.

**More Info**
[Android Studio](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio.html#download)
- A rich layout editor that allows you to drag-and-drop UI components, preview layouts on multiple screen configurations, and much more.

Comment: not looks like real question :( please add some reference link or some more description to understand easily.

Comment: Android Studio available is preview release. If you are new to Java, i would suggest you to use more stable IDE

Comment: Thanks. I am trying to learn coding in Android using this tool.

Comment: You should use IDEA (which Studio is based on) or Eclipse.

Comment: I think this question and questions like it are related to programming. You should try and loosen up.

Comment: Please reopen. On topic questions include "...software tools commonly used by programmers". http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I figured it out. To show the rich layout tool you have to open the file in the layout directory, "src/main/res/layout". For me this file is, "login.xml".

Also, note that at the bottom of the screen are two tabs, "Design" and "Text".

[image]

Comment: As solange points out in the following post, you might not be able to see these two bottom tabs, "Design" and "Text", if you're using the darker Dracula theme. Switch back to the Default theme and see if they are there. (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16660039/where-is-android-studio-layout-preview)