# Layout preview not working in Android Studio

Tags: eclipse, android-layout, android-studio

I ported an android project from Eclipse to Android Studio. The project builds just fine. However I am not able to see any layout preview. When I go to the Design tab of a layout I get a

> Loading Configuration...

message that never goes away (see image).

[image]

I have set correctly the Android SDK in the project structure.
This happens with all the xml files and I am not able to open the "Preview" window from

> View ->  Tool Windows -> Preview

I tried creating a new project and everything was showing fine. Am I missing something? Anyone faced a similar issue? Is there a chance that this is happening because the folder structure is not the default one? (The layouts are not under **project/src/main/res/layout** but under **project/res/layout**)

Comment: I have the same problem and in my case the layouts are in the default folder.

Comment: I had to mess around with the project..and at some point it worked. I don't know how though. My guess would be that creating a new project and adding your source code would work every time. Sorry for not being very clear, but honestly I was surprized even myself that it worked.

Comment: Possible Duplicate: [endless-loading-configuration-in-design-view](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17596295/endless-loading-configuration-in-design-view/30745990#30745990)

Answer (score 9):

Try this

1. Build> Clean Project
2. Build> Rebuild Project

It worked for me

Answer (score 4):

Just do a right click on the layout preview and click on

```
Show Included in contentmain.xml
```

you can see it in the following image
[image]

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and I solved as follow

1. Update all build.gradle files with:

classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.5.+'

Now android studio 0.2.+ uses gradle 0.5

1. Closes de IDE and via Terminal/Console
2. Do a clean: $gradle clean
3. Do a build: $gradle build
4. Assemble it: $gradle assembleDebug
5. Open the Android Studio and be happy ;)

Answer (score 1):

Close android studio and go to path as follow:
C:\Users\user\ .AndroidStudio1.2\restart
There is a file named restarter,double click on it and open android studio again,create a new project and enjoy it

Comment: "Create a new project" - how does that help someone migrating an existing project from Eclipse to Android Studio?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is better to use the 0.3.6 version (latest), with this version of gradle : com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.6.+

Bear in mind that Android Studio will be expecting the Android SDK already installed (as I suppose you have), and also the environment variables ANDROID_HOME and GRADLE_HOME.

Answer (score 0):

Try updating your API to the latest version in the SDK manager ---- worked for me

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem Follow this step :

- First uninstall old android studio and delete .androidstudio file from  C:\Users\yourpcname
- update api to latest version in SDK manager.
- Install [Latest Android Studio Canary Build: 2.0 Preview 9](http://tools.android.com/download/studio/canary/latest)

Done

Answer (score 0):

In Android Studio

File>Invalidate Caches/Restart

that's how i fixed

Answer (score 0):

You can try :

1. Select Preview window(Focus on it)
2. Unselect Floating mode and Pinned mode
3. goto  Window -> Active Tool Window ->
4. Unselect Floating mode and Pinned mode
5. Now you can see Docked window option here(Window -> Active Tool Window ->)
6. Select Docked Window