# Endless "Loading Configuration" in Design view

Tags: android, android-studio

Every time I open an activity layout in order to view its design, I can't see anything, and there's a "Loading configuration" message. How to solve it?

Looks like this is related to the following issue: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=56691&q=%22Loading%20Configuration%22&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars

Comment: I gave the Android studio a try and it does not seem to be production ready in some cases. Eclipse ADT is a better choice in my humble opinion.

Comment: Update: IntelliJ IDEA seems the best right now.

Comment: Possible Duplicate: [layout-preview-not-working-in-android-studio](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17365015/layout-preview-not-working-in-android-studio)

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue and it got solved by using the menu item: File->Invalidate Caches/Restart

Comment: Exactly what I needed to do

Answer (score 1):

Try to delete the **build** folder.

---

Here are the details:

Yesterday(2015/6/10) I faced to the same problem, and I solved it by using beyond compare:

- This problem occured after a forced upgrade.
- I have 2 projects, one worked(newly created) and one doesn't.
- So I used beyond compare to compare the 2 projects' folders.
- Luckily I found **build** folder of the not-worked never changed even though I clear cache, restart and rebuild it several times.
- **build** folder deleted and everything worked fine now.

Answer (score 0):

I've had this issue before, and it was usually not long after an error had come up.

Check the Event Log for errors. Usually a restart of the IDE fixed it for me though I appreciate that's not ideal. The errors weren't anything specific I think just teething issues with Android Studio - tis just preview software after all.