# Android Studio - No Design Options?

Tags: java, android, linux, user-interface

[image]

Any way, I don't have a design option to make my program's UI. Any ideas?

This is not a DUPE! I am using Linux and this isn't working. I specifically said it WAS NOT a dupe but it was still marked anyway, oh well.

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/q/16660039/612920

Comment: I have already tried them answers, did not work.

Comment: Don't you have View -> Tool Windows -> Preview?

Comment: I think it's better if you provide screenshots that make clear it's not a dupe...

Comment: I'm on Linux. I've told you that and I have tried the other answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the menu bar

Select tools>-android>-SDK manager

and download the SDK build tools, SDK platform and Google API's

Restart IDE