# No Graphical Layout in Android Studio 1.3.2

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm an experienced Xcode developer who is beginning work in Android Studio 1.3.2. I am trying to open an XML file for a tutorial in the "Graphical Layout" view in AS but I have no Graphical Layout Button at the bottom of the screen. How can I open it?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is two mode **Design** and **Text**
just double click in .xml file and you will see something look like this
[image]

if you dont have this then try to use View>window tool>preview

[image]

For more detail [click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16660039/where-is-android-studio-layout-preview)

Comment: My version does not have this!

Comment: See the photo I just added.

Answer (score 0):

Solved -

1) File -> Project Structure -> Project. No Project SDK was set for some reason. Selected Android API 23 Platform.

2)File -> Project Structure -> Modules. Add an android facet to the project drop down menu.