# Preview in Android Studio gets removed from display when editing xml files

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, preview

Usually when in the XML text editor you also have the option to view the preview of what the display will look like when running the application. Somehow I disabled this. Now when I click on my XML file to add code, the preview gets taken out of the display. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: Do you still have the Design tab below?

Comment: add snap of your screen

Answer (score 0):

If you dont have  preview option visible then go for this one:

**`View` -> `Tool Windows` -> `Preview`**

For more detail consult this stackoverflow post-
[Where is Android Studio layout preview?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16660039/where-is-android-studio-layout-preview)