# My preview button is missing, help me find it?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

I am completely new to app development in fact i just downloaded the software Android Studio 2.2.2. I dont know if something went wrong but there is no preview button on the right side or anywhere else. Keep in mind the i have not started writing any code yet. Any help will be appreciated.  Thank you so much for your time and help

[studio image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bjISM.png)

Comment: please post screenshot

Comment: i think you are looking for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16660039/where-is-android-studio-layout-preview

Comment: In your screenshot you have an error _Non zero exit value 2_. Are u sure u need the solution for preview button or that error?

Comment: @Raghavendra At first solve `Non zero exit value 2` problem then #preview .

Comment: Check this It might help to solve the first issue [Non zero exit value 2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29756188/java-finished-with-non-zero-exit-value-2-android-gradle)

Answer (score 0):

To Solve. `Java finished with non-zero exit value 2 - Android Gradle` follow this answer [Java finished with non-zero exit value 2 - Android Gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29756188/java-finished-with-non-zero-exit-value-2-android-gradle)

And then for preview button try this: `View` -> `Tool Windows` -> `Preview`

[image]

Follow the link provided in comments by IntelliJ Amiya.

Comment: I am sorry but i dont have that option either under **Tool Windows**.  The list goes- a faded 'Palette', faded Properties, Terminal, then faded theme preview. Also initially the app was talking a lot of time to install to i cancelled it a couple of times before finally having it install properly, so maybe because of that something happened with the libraries. I deleted it once and installed it again but it just started without the long installation process-@priya jagtab

Comment: is your problem solved? @user3744516

Comment: Yes, my previous problem got solved. Thank you so much, but now as you expected(i guess) i am facing "Java finished with non-zero exit value 2 - Android Gradle" I cant fix this. That is my simple hello world project is not getting printed out in the preview

Comment: ok. I will try to find solution. best of luck @user3744516