# Can't see preview of android studio

Tags: android-studio

I recently installed android studio but can't see the preview of the app.

[image: my android studio screenshot]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where is Android Studio layout preview?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16660039/where-is-android-studio-layout-preview)

Comment: Your Gradle project sync failed. And there is a `NullPointerException`... Fix those first

Answer (score 1):

When you switch in the `Layout.xml`, on the bottom you will see two options: -Design -Text.  Chose `Text` and then on the top right you will see `Preview` appears and so you can click `Preview`.

Comment: the preview buttons is shown there but when I open that there is nothing. Just a plus sign there

Answer (score 1):

Go to Res->values->styles and change the name of your theme to base.theme. ex-> Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar to Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar

Answer (score 0):

Please notice the  value on the right of the small android icon, just above where the "preview" should be. 
There you should pick the API in wish the representation is made. If theres nothing to select there, you will need to install the necessary API packages.

[image]