# Android Studio design view - mockup not appearing

Tags: android, android-studio

I just installed Android Studio 2.3.3 and I followed the steps given on Tutorials Point website for this installation. The install process was successful. I then created a new project as shown in the screen below. 
 [image] 
 In the install instructions, it was shown that I will see the mockup as shown in screenshot below. However, it does not show the mobile mockup in design view. What am I missing? Or how do I get the mockup in design view? 
 [image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where is Android Studio layout preview?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16660039/where-is-android-studio-layout-preview)

Comment: @DaveNOTDavid I tried preview but its still showing as shown in screenshot 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, viewing the XML design preview of your app with a **mobile device frame** around it is deprecated for the latest stable versions of Android Studio.

Comment: Okay... I didn't know that. Thank you for sharing this info. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Please Follow below steps:

> View -> Tool Windows -> Preview.

Select Preview.

Comment: Sangram, I am already in preview. Its the preview that is not showing mobile mockup... it is showing as shown in screenshot 1