# Android Studio Properties in Property Window Missing

Tags: android, android-studio

I am newbie to Android. I am using Android Studio 2.3.3 on mac OS. The property list in property window is missing in my android studio. I was showing few days back. I have tried few things from googling but didn't work for me. 
[image]

[image]

Comment: If you press shift+f12 it will restore the default layout.

Comment: @Neha didn't work for me.

Comment: try to reset UI of an android studio.

Comment: @Neha plz give me the steps to reset UI

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where is Android Studio layout preview?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16660039/where-is-android-studio-layout-preview)

Comment: View -> Tool Window -> Preview

Comment: It will reset android studio: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19384033/how-to-reset-android-studio

Comment: I was not talking about preview. Property list is missing in my android studio

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
View -> Tool Window -> Preview
```