# I accidentally closed the preview bar in Android Studio 3.1.3, How do I get it back?

Tags: android-studio-3.1.3

[I have accidentlly closed the Preview bar which was present in the Top-Left Corner of the screen, How do I get it back?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dhA71.png)

Comment: Have a look : https://stackoverflow.com/a/16660112/7874047

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no preview in .java file. The preview is available in .xml file
[See in this image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e1b2Q.png)

Comment: i hope this answer helped you in your problem