# How to see XML files code in Android Studio 3.6.1

Tags: android, xml, android-studio

I have updated my android studio to 3.6.1 . Everything looks so good but i could not found the xml files code to view. They have removed the left side corner options to view design / code of xml file. Now how can i see it?

Comment: It has answer about Android Studio 3.6.1 also https://stackoverflow.com/a/60457932/1318946

Answer (score 37):

They move the buttons in top right corner under the files opened. Now you have 3 options instead of 2!

[image: They move the buttons in top right corner under the files opened]

Answer (score 13):

Finally i found it. They have moved this options to right of top corner with two icons for code and design views 
[image: See the below image for more details]

Comment: I just seen your answers after i post my answer here . Also i have upvoted too

Comment: I just did now.

Comment: this answer is not necessary. already has been answered

Answer (score 9):

[image: https://imgur.com/XMIn9hB]
Click this button to view xml.

Answer (score 9):

[image]

You have three selections on top right of screen.

Comment: They have changed this option menu's location in android studio 3.6.1. They have moved to right side top corner

Comment: As we said you.

Answer (score 3):

Android Studio 3.6.1

Trick to default open split design/ code for xml file

```
File -> Settings -> Editor -> Layout Editor -> check the checkbox "Prefer XML Editor"

On Windows ctrl + Shift + A -> prefer XML...
```

[image: output]

Comment: How do I display the XML editor preview on startup?

Answer (score 2):

The Simple way with keyboard shortcut

> Alt + Shift + Arrow keys L-R

Answer (score 0):

Design editors, such as the Layout Editor and Navigation Editor, now provide a Split view that enables you to see both the Design and Code views of your UI at the same time. To enable split view, click the Split icon   in the top-right corner of the editor window.

Comment: already we could see that in previous versions. no wonder about that.