# Android studio 3.6.1, Layout not opening in an editor. Studio not showing the XML editor only shows the design part of layout?

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-layout, editor

When i opened studio(`Android studio 3.6.1`) today. The layouts are not opening in an XML editor its **not showing the XML editor but only the design part**.

Screenshot below

[image]

I tried `invalidate cache and restart, clean project, build project, sync gradle files`, restarted  my system nothing works.

**What is causing this odd behaviour ?**

Comment: See my answer for this question please: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60595805/how-to-see-xml-files-code-in-android-studio-3-6-1/60595883#60595883

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to see XML files code in Android Studio 3.6.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60595805/how-to-see-xml-files-code-in-android-studio-3-6-1)

Comment: This question already has an answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/16660112/10752944

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where is Android Studio layout preview?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16660039/where-is-android-studio-layout-preview)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Click on button which is top right corner.

[image]

Also, Update Android Studio 3.6.2 because in 3.6.1 some databinding issue is there.

Comment: If this is correct answer and if it help you then please accept answer @Amal P

Comment: is there any key board shortcut for this?

Answer (score 2):

Please look at top Right corner. You'll see three diffrent icon. Now you know :)

Answer (score 2):

In android studio 3.6.1 designing and editor shifted to the upper right corner.