# Android Studio - rendering design not working properly after update

Tags: android, android-studio

I don't know what happened to Android Studio, but after update Design preview of the project is not working property. Look what happend:
[image: Text]
I have noticed that after update, SDK has been changed so I installed back SDK used in project but the result is the same. Also I have tried to reinstall android studio but with no result too.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60595805/how-to-see-xml-files-code-in-android-studio-3-6-1/60595883#60595883

Comment: Preview of XML has been changed in new version

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to see XML files code in Android Studio 3.6.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60595805/how-to-see-xml-files-code-in-android-studio-3-6-1)

Answer (score 0):

If you are worried about where the **`code pane`** is, that is now at the top right corner. You have the option to switch between **`code`**, **`design`** or both now.

If you are worried that the project is not refreshing to the artifacts such as colors as shown in the error above, then check what **`BaseTheme`** your project is implementing and try to clean and **`rebuild`** your project. **`Material Theme`** can cause such issues as it follows a different naming convention than **`AppCompat`**.