# Android Studio 3.6.3 not showing suggestions in XML

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-layout

I upgraded my Android studio from 3.6.1 to 3.6.3 and it suddenly stopped showing any suggestions in the xml files.

Did invalidate cache and restart, deleted build folder and everything that should help but no luck.

Anyone getting the same issue?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60595805/how-to-see-xml-files-code-in-android-studio-3-6-1/60595883#60595883

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to see XML files code in Android Studio 3.6.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60595805/how-to-see-xml-files-code-in-android-studio-3-6-1)

Comment: I'm talking about autocomplete suggestions, not the preview

Comment: where is autocomplete in your question?!

Comment: When you press "<" in XML , it shows the suggestions like <TextView... and stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Finally it worked when I deleted the caches folder from the Library directory in my Mac.