# How to view Layout Editor instead of XML code in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin

[Android Studio Problem Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t8jyh.jpg)

I'm new to android programming, but when I opened android studio, I can't see the layout editor. I've tried opening new projects from scratch, but the same thing happens. It just shows the XML code editor instead of the "drag and drop" layout editor. Does anyone know how to fix this? 
Thanks.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60595883/12478830

Answer (score 1):

In the SS you have posted there is build running, and layout editor is available only after build is finished.

nonetheless, after build is finished you can easily access layout editor in android studio 3.6 by pressing the buttons near top-right corner
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Did you check by pressing <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>, Kindly press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd> on the design screen and it will open the XML layout for you.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

There are three options for viewing your layout resources. You can view the XML, the XML along with the design, or just the design. You can navigate through these options by clicking the buttons of the top right of this image